# Magento cant make an order

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, onestepcheckout

I have an installation of Magento 1.9.2. I am using a custom theme, and anytime I try and place an order it kicks off the Ajax on the page and then stops with no error messages, but does leave a log:

```
ERR (3): User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 4039
```

I have spent 2 days trying to get to the bottom of this with no joy. It doesn't matter what payment method I use its always the same.

Comment: Refer this Link

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15012/user-error-some-transactions-have-not-been-committed-or-rolled-back



Hope it willl help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to log all MySQL queries to see what wrong here. lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.

Open the file `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and change the value of the protected property `$_debug` to `true`. You can also change the value of `$_logQueryTime` which is especially handy when debugging slowdowns. Once you make this change all queries will be logged in the file `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log`

Hope this will help you. Please put your corrupted query here if you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had today the same problem. Magento 1.9.2.4 with a custom theme. Everything worked fine, expect the checkout-process. The custom theme used the PHP short open tag `<? php code ?>` . After enabling short_open_tag in the php.ini, everything works fine.